# UINavigationController replacement in QML for side menu / Drawer

Tags: qt, navigation, qml, qtquick2

Lets say my app uses a `StackLayout` together with a `TabBar` on the bottom and a `ToolBar` on the top for the main window layout, and on top of that I have a `Drawer` which drags in a menu from the left side when a button in the `ToolBar` is pressed.

So far, so standard.

Now how would I implement the `Drawer` featuring several levels deep of nested menu hierarchy? In XCode I would just use a `UINavigationController` and push pages on it when I go down a level, and pop the page when I go a level up.

How would I do this in QML? Should I just put *another* `StackLayout` inside the `Drawer`?

Comment: You could do the StackLayout inside the Drawer, sure. A StackView may be more appropriate since you are pushing and popping though.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, gonna check it out. Still unfamiliar with lots of QML components.